# Expanding a node till its child has a sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treetable

Consider adding a feature using **JQuery - treetable plugin.**

Initially a node (say, ***a***) should be in collapsed state, and then I just want to perform an operation that, when I click on the node ***a***, the tree should expand till when its child has sibling(s), also both that child and its sibling(s) node(s) should be in collapsed state.

An example:

a has one child b (a-b)

b has one child b1, (a-b-b1)

b1 has one child b2, (a-b-b1-b2)

b2 has two children b3 & b4 (a-b-b1-b2-b3&b4),

b3 has one child b5 (a-b-b1-b2-b3-b5)

b4 has one child b6 (a-b-b1-b2-b4-b6)

b6 has two children (a-b-b1-b2-b4-b7&b8)

b7 has one child b9 (a-b-b1-b2-b4-b7-b9)

b8 has one child b10 (a-b-b1-b2-b4-b7-b10)

The corresponding tree structure is as follows:
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATMG3.png)

The colors indicates that, when I click "***a***" it should expand till "b3" and "b4" automatically. Similarly, if I click "b4" it should expand till "b7" and "b8".

***HTML snippet***

```html
<div class="container">
            <h1>Toggling</h1>
         <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tr class="level_0" id="a"><td>a</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_1 parent_a" id="b"><td>b</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_2 parent_b" id="b1"><td>b1</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_3 parent_b1" id="b2"><td>b2</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_4 parent_b2" id="b3"><td>b3</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_4 parent_b2" id="b4"><td>b4</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_5 parent_b3" id="b5"><td>b5</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_5 parent_b4" id="b6"><td>b6</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_6 parent_b6" id="b7"><td>b7</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_6 parent_b6" id="b8"><td>b8</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_7 parent_b7" id="b9"><td>b9</td></tr>
          <tr class="level_7 parent_b8" id="b10"><td>b10</td></tr>
         </table>
</div>
```

***jQuery snippet***

```js
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') throw "jQuery Required";

jQuery(function ($) {
 var treeTable = {
  parentClassPrefix : '',
  collapsedClass : 'expanded',
  init : function(parentClassPrefix) {
   this.parentClassPrefix = parentClassPrefix;
   $('table').on('click', 'tr', function () { 
    treeTable.toggleRowChildren($(this));
   });
  },
  toggleRowChildren : function(parentRow) {
   var childClass = this.parentClassPrefix+parentRow.attr('id');
   var childrenRows = $('tr', parentRow.parent()).filter('.'+childClass);
   childrenRows.toggle();
   childrenRows.each(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass(treeTable.collapsedClass)) {
     treeTable.toggleRowChildren($(this));
    }
   });
   parentRow.toggleClass(this.collapsedClass);
  }
 };
 
 treeTable.init('parent_');
});
```

The execution can be seen in JSFiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/angsusv7/).
**Note:** Changes can be monitored by clicking on the node ***a***.

Now, I want to know what changes should I make in the jQuery to achieve the desired output of expanding till *sibling node* as discussed earlier.

Comment: is it fine to make the DOM corresponding to the hierarchy, then it would be easy using jQuery, make a function getEndPointOf Expansion(container){ this  iterate over each node in the container and on finding the first node that has children return it} then call on the expand function for that

Comment: if not the other option is to create an object that holds the design of the hierarchy and use the same  'getEndPointOf Expansion()'

Comment: @nivendha: Could you provide a sample code block for the case which I discussed? That would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var store={};
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr').each(function(i,ele){
 dt=$(ele).data(),child=$(ele).attr('id')
if(!store[dt.parent]){
    store[dt.parent]=[];
}
store[dt.parent].push(child);
});

//console.log(store);//your hierarchy object is ready
  //uncoment and check

$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () { 
                $('tr').removeClass('expand');
                toggleRowChildren($(this));
});

function toggleRowChildren(startNode){
    var id=startNode.attr('id');
    startNode.addClass('expand');
    if(typeof store[id]==='undefined'){
        //this is the last leaf node nothing to expand
        return;
    }
    if(store[id].length>1){
        var leafNodes=store[id];
        for (var i = 0; i < leafNodes.length; i++) {
            $('#'+leafNodes[i]).addClass('expand');
        }
    }else{
        var childId=store[id][0];
        toggleRowChildren($('#'+childId));
    }
}
})
```

```css
.expand td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="container">
            <h1>Toggling</h1>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr  data-parent='HEAD' class="level_0" id="a"><td>a</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='a' class="level_1 parent_a" id="b"><td>b</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b'   class="level_2 parent_b" id="b1"><td>b1</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b1'   class="level_3 parent_b1" id="b2"><td>b2</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b2'   class="level_4 parent_b2" id="b3"><td>b3</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b2'   class="level_4 parent_b2" id="b4"><td>b4</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b3'   class="level_5 parent_b3" id="b5"><td>b5</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b4'   class="level_5 parent_b4" id="b6"><td>b6</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b6'   class="level_6 parent_b6" id="b7"><td>b7</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b6'   class="level_6 parent_b6" id="b8"><td>b8</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b7'   class="level_7 parent_b7" id="b9"><td>b9</td></tr>
                <tr  data-parent='b8'   class="level_7 parent_b8" id="b10"><td>b10</td></tr>
            </table>
</div>
```